# how to get around amazon product advertising API request maximum

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, amazon-advertising-api

i am using the amazon API product description in order to get price lists for specific items in their database. however after getting a few thousand items i am getting:

```
System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException was unhandled
  Message="The HTTP service located at https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService is too busy. "
```

it looks like they do not want users to bother them too much with too many requests.

i will need to do probably around 1,000,000 requests per day.

i am wondering if there is any way to get over this limit?

here is how i am request my data:

```
// prepare the first ItemSearchRequest
                // prepare a second ItemSearchRequest
                ItemSearchRequest request1 = new ItemSearchRequest();
                request1.SearchIndex = "All";
                request1.Keywords = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                request1.ItemPage = "1";
                request1.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "OfferSummary" };

                // batch the two requests together
                ItemSearch itemSearch = new ItemSearch();
                itemSearch.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request1 };
                itemSearch.AWSAccessKeyId = accessKeyId;

                // issue the ItemSearch request
                ItemSearchResponse response = client.ItemSearch(itemSearch);
```

Answer (score 3):

You would contact Amazon and ask them. You don't try to "get around" it.

I suppose you could get a bunch of servers on different IPs. But just ask Amazon, it's the right thing to do.